# Particular religious festivities that are occuring highlighted during a whole company meeting. Should I highlight this?

Tags: united-kingdom, meetings, religion

During a whole company meeting, in the first half of this year, there was an occasion in which two members of the company, one Jewish and the other Muslim, gave an overview of Passover and Eid, respectively. As someone that identifies as a Christian, it seemed a little out of place that there was no-one that gave an overview of Easter, as this is another religious event that occurs roughly around the same time as Passover and Eid (at least in 2022.)

Would it be appropriate to reach out to HR and request that someone gives an overview of Easter, in Future?

Comment: What was the nature of the meeting?  What was the context for giving an overview of Passover and Eid?

Comment: @sf02 The meeting was a general, whole company meeting. eg- updates on company performance, new people that have been hired, and to highlight events that have happened/are going to happen

Comment: I'm a little confused about the close vote for company policy. Is the idea that there might be a company policy for/against OP asking HR this question?

Comment: Why do you feel the need for this? It's not a competition

Answer (score 21):

The vast majority of people in the UK know when Easter is, and what it's about. This is not true for festivals from other religions.

This means that people may not know what the festivals entail, and also about the other things that go on around those times (such as Muslims fasting before Eid) - so making sure that people are aware of them can help them be accommodating, and can avoid potential awkwardness (like someone arranging a special company lunch during Ramadan).

If you believe that there are a significant number of people in your office who don't know what Easter is and what it entails (such as the company closing for several days over the bank holidays), then I'm sure HR would be happy to let *you* give an overview of it in a meeting. But asking HR to try and find someone else to give a talk about religion is not appropriate.

Personally, I have no idea when Eid is. So for someone to say in a meeting "Eid is on $date, which means that I won't be eating or drinking during the day for the next 30 days, so please be aware that $foo" is useful. Giving a long lecture on it (or evangelising) would be less appropriate, unless people in the meeting are expressing a particular interest.

Comment: Agree this is a thing for you to do.  Practically, people may be OOO some of Easter week and be abstaining some from meat during Lent (depending on how traditional your area is) and those bear mention.

Comment: @mxyzplk Good Friday and Easter Monday are bank holidays in the UK, so many companies will be completely closed those days.